# Windows 10 - Decrypt EFS encrypted

Tags: windows-10, decryption

I encrypted files using **EFS tool** on my PC and then transferred them to another PC without transfer the certificate used to encrypt data, but then I want to retrieve them. I moved it encrypted from the other device to my device but I could not decrypt it. It appears in the extension of **.PFILE**.

Comment: Did you transfer the certificate used to encrypt the data?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Ramhound I have edit it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So is the certificate used to encrypt the file installed on the same computer where you're trying to decrypt it? It's unclear from your question whether that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I encrypted files using EFS tool on my PC and then transferred them to another PC without transfer the certificate used to encrypt data, but then I want to retrieve them.

If you do not have the certificate, used to encrypt the data, then you cannot decrypt the encrypted the data.  What you want is not possible without the certificate installed on the PC in question.

Answer (score 0):

For any proper and modern encryption method, the ability to decrypt manually, without the required decryption key, is a function of mathematics using very large numbers that generally represent very long periods of time. This makes decryption without the correct decryption key effectively impossible.

If you still have access to the key, get the key and use it. If you lost the key and no longer have it in any storage or backup, the data is effectively lost.

When I say "effectively lost" I mean that it would take you on an averagely powerful computer dozens to hundreds of years or more to decrypt the data.